# Trying to get query in app.get function using express in node.js

Tags: node.js, express, get

I'm trying to get query after 'status.html' such as `localhost:3000/status.html?channel="string that I want to get"`.

So I wrote the code like below.

```
app.get('/status.html', isLoggedIn, function(res, req){
  if (req.query.channel){
    if (req.isAuthenticated()){
      res.redirect('/status');

    }else{
      console.log("Please Log in to access to this webpage");
      res.redirect('/login');

    }
  }
});
```

However, it doesn't even go through app.get '/status.html'...

What is my problem here...?
Can anyone help me out here..?

Thank you

Just in case, my directory is set as below

```
node_modules
public
  images
  javascripts
  js
  stylesheets
  status.html
routes
views
  login
app.js
package.json
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`app.get(path, callback)` is a route

a path can be a `string` a `a regex pattern`

```
// if you use `/status.html` then html `href` should as be same path
// `/status.html`
// app.get('/status.html', isLoggedIn, function(res, req){

app.get('/status', isLoggedIn, function(res, req){
      if (req.query.channel){
        if (req.isAuthenticated()){
          res.redirect('/status');

        }else{
          console.log("Please Log in to access to this webpage");
          res.redirect('/login');
        }
      }
    });
```

in your html file you have to create an anchor tag with `href`

html file

```
// <a href ="/status.html" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Status</a>
<a href ="/status" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Status</a>
```

when you click the status button it will call the `/status` route `app.get()`

```
// `/status.html` is just a route path it has nothing to do with html files
```

Comment: Thank you for replying me back! :) Hm.. I see.. I already set and redirect to 'localhost:3000/status.html' from the code and worked with no problem, so I thought I can use app.get('/status.html'...) thing.... :'(

Comment: `localhost:3000/status.html` means you are statically loading a html file,

have a look at express `res.sendFile()` function

Comment: Thanks! :) I'll look at express res.sendFile() function :) Once again Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the file status.html from your public directory and create route , basically it is requesting to your public directory,
If you want to use status.html in public directory, you can implement ajax work there.

Comment: Thank you for replying me back! :) How can I do with ajax...? :'(